# Selenium how to click on placeholde inside div

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

hi. I want to click on this placeholder inside div, how can I do it, I tried Xpath but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `input` field is inside an iframe. You have to switch to `iframe` first and then try to `sendkeys`.

```
IWebElement iframeElement= driver.FindElement(By.Name("top"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeElement);

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));

element.SendKeys("text");
```

**Note: As in question there is no detail about iframe `iframeElement` so I took this name from `input` element. You can change locator if it is not correct**